# Check if an array of array contains an array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, contains

Here are two columns of my dataframe (df):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ["a"] | [["a"], ["b"]] |
| ["c"] | [["a"], ["b"]] |

I want to create an array that tells whether the array in column A is in the array of array which is in column B, like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["a"] | [["a"], ["b"]] | True |
| ["c"] | [["a"], ["b"]] | False |

I tried `df.select("A", "B", array_contains(F.col("B"), F.col("A")).alias("C"))` but got an error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: The feature is not supported: literal for '' of class java.util.ArrayList

It seems that array of array isn't implemented in PySpark. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to use [`array_contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html#pyspark-sql-functions-array-contains) within an [`expr()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html#pyspark-sql-functions-expr).

For a sample like the following

```
+------+-------------+
|    c1|           c2|
+------+-------------+
|   [a]|   [[a], [b]]|
|   [c]|   [[a], [b]]|
|   [a]|[[a, b], [c]]|
|[a, b]|[[a, b], [c]]|
+------+-------------+
```

Flattening it might give you erroneous results considering the third row. But `array_contains` wouldn't.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('overlap', func.expr('array_contains(c2, c1)')). \
    show()

# +------+-------------+-------+
# |    c1|           c2|overlap|
# +------+-------------+-------+
# |   [a]|   [[a], [b]]|   true|
# |   [c]|   [[a], [b]]|  false|
# |   [a]|[[a, b], [c]]|  false|
# |[a, b]|[[a, b], [c]]|   true|
# +------+-------------+-------+
```

---

example using `flatten`

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('overlap_with_flatten', func.expr('arrays_overlap(c1, flatten(c2))')). \
    show()

# +------+-------------+--------------------+
# |    c1|           c2|overlap_with_flatten|
# +------+-------------+--------------------+
# |   [a]|   [[a], [b]]|                true|
# |   [c]|   [[a], [b]]|               false|
# |   [a]|[[a, b], [c]]|                true|
# |[a, b]|[[a, b], [c]]|                true|
# +------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` and `transform` functions in SQL `expr`.

```
df = df.withColumn('C', F.expr('exists(transform(B, x -> x == A), x -> x is true)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using [`arrays_overlap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap) after [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten) is used on the column "B".

```py
F.arrays_overlap("A", F.flatten("B"))
```

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["a"], [["a"], ["b"]]),
     (["c"], [["a"], ["b"]])],
    ['A', 'B'])

df = df.withColumn("C", F.arrays_overlap("A", F.flatten("B")))

df.show()
# +---+----------+-----+
# |  A|         B|    C|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |[a]|[[a], [b]]| true|
# |[c]|[[a], [b]]|false|
# +---+----------+-----+
```